# Install point cloud library (PCL) in python

Tags: python, point-cloud-library

I'm new to using PCL and have no experience using C++ and little experience using Python. I am trying to use PCL in python but appear to be encountering a few problems calling any of the modules. I have tried following some of the online tutorials but when I try and call a module such as pcl.PointCloud() I get an error saying that the module object has no attribute 'PointCloud'. I have tried this with other modules. Does anybody know why this is occurring and how I can overcome this problem please?

Comment: It's going to very difficult to answer your question properly without your code where you're encountrying your error. Please can you supply a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code?

Comment: What is your script name?

Comment: @DavidBuck my problem is related to installing PCL. have you ever worked with that? this is developed in c++ but someone in GitHub  install it in python. in this link you can see that: https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl

Comment: @PeterWood sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: You would see this error if your script is named pcl.py